# Refresh div content, without Jquery, AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

How do you use just plain JS to refresh the content of the an AJAX inserted div? So many examples use Jquery but I'm trying to stay light and not use Jquery. What I have so far:

-index. php the html page
-livedata. php html of the section with the live data
-scripts. js file with the JS

I want to refresh page every 10 seconds.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();                 // Create XMLHttpRequest object

xhr.onload = function() {                       // When response has loaded
  // The following conditional check will not work locally - only on a server
  if(xhr.status === 200) {                       // If server status was ok
    document.getElementById('live').innerHTML = xhr.responseText; // Update
  }
};

xhr.open('GET', 'livedata.php', true);        // Prepare the request
xhr.send(null);                                 // Send the request
```

Just for reference here is index.php

```
    <!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <section id="live">
        <p>please wait... loading content</p>
    </section>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does your code work - looks like it should update once ... for every 10 seconds, use a `setInterval`

Comment: Seems fine. Check network tab in developer tools of your browser, see what it returns when you send request to livedata.php.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
function getData() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();                 // Create XMLHttpRequest object

  xhr.onload = function() {                       // When response has loaded
    // The following conditional check will not work locally - only on a server
    if(xhr.status === 200) {                       // If server status was ok
      document.getElementById('live').innerHTML = xhr.responseText; // Update
    }
  };

  xhr.open('GET', 'livedata.php', true);        // Prepare the request
  xhr.send(null);                                 // Send the request
}

setInterval(getData, 1000*10);
```

Comment: When I first load the page I have to wait 10 second for the data to come up then it starts refreshing every 10 seconds? I would like the data to load right away then start refreshing. Anyone have suggestion how to do that?

Comment: It's easy to add a line in the script.
window.onload = getData();